# How can i use setEnabled for a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I got this code in a `JFrame`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String user = textField.getText();
            String pass = new String(passTextField.getPassword());
            if(user.equals(username)&&pass.equals(password)){
                mf.setEnabled(true);
                validate();
                Password.this.dispose();}
            else{
            mf.setEnabled(false);

            }
        }
    }`
```

basically it is a code for a password , and when the user is an admin the code should enable all the `JMenuItems` for the admin, i used `mf.setEbanled(true);` (mf an Object of another JFrame) but this method won't work, how can i make all the Jmenu items to be enable?

//

in the main `JFrame`

```
JMenuItem mntmLogin = new JMenuItem("Login");
    mntmLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             Password p = new Password(); // what argument should this have?
                p.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I think you must pass the `mf` object to the constructor of your login `jFrame` !!

Comment: I passed the object to the password `JFrame` ,  but how can i use it in the  main `JFrame` to make it work?

Comment: is `mf` an object of the main JFrame ??

Comment: yes `mf` is an object of the main `JFrame`.

Comment: So you should pass it to Password jFrame like that : `Password p = new Password(mf);` (change your password constructor )and in your Password `jFrame` create a locale variable and assign `mf` to it then manupilate your local var as you like !!